# Learning Dataview webpart and xsl

Tags: 2010, xslt, data-view-web-part

I have taken over a Sharepoint 2007 site and been tasked to migrate / recreate much of it to a separate Sharepoint 2010 site. I am still learning many aspects of Sharepoint. The old site has many pages that have custom dataview webparts displaying information from lists in tables, different ways, based on who is signed in etc.

1.) Is there a recommended way for modifying this stuff? I see there is XSL editor and  Parameters Editor on the webpart menu. There is also the code when I export the webpart and finally the list of code in SPD. Is there pitfall from updating these using one way or the other?

2.) Is there / what would be the best way to copy these or the xsl from these if they are reusable from 2007? I understand the GUIDs on my lists would be different, but should I change anything else?

3.)How does the <'xsl> tie together with the rest of it like your datasource, fields etc

4.) Is there recommended reading somewhere for how to go from inserting an empty dataview to correctly formatted data with custom edited xsl / html from start to finish? All I can find is snippets of everything in between and I am struggling to put it all together. Can someone walk me through or send me somewhere that goes A to Z from inserting dataview, changing the xsl, modifying adding fields or modifying your result set, and displaying those modified results in a custom way (say a table with a picture next to each item in a row).

I know it's a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a search for "Laura Rogers Data View Web Part" and review articles on EndUserSharePoint.com (alot of her articles are there).

She covers quite a bit on how to use them and style with XSLT.  You will find others that have contributed on the topic there as well.

XSLT is the view engine - it's going to generated based on your data source, and so is dependent on it.  You may want to attempt at upgrading your current site.  IF you have access to the server or an admin that can help out.

1. Migrate or copy your 2007 site into a dedicated database.
2. Attach Database to 2010 farm and upgrade the database.
3. Upgrade the site to 2010.

This may be all you need - but if there are issues, you may still be able to export the lists and web parts that do work and import them into your site.  It may seem like a lot of work here but it would actually progress pretty quickly and you would know within an hour if this will work for you (assuming it's not a 200GB site you are upgrading).

Comment: So do folks typically just use SPD to get the layout they want and then tweak the xsl as necessary? Versus trying to everything from scratch with xsl? As for upgrade. Unfortunately that option is not available. I was looking instead for a step by step to copy existing 2007 DVWP to 2010.

Comment: I don't' do much XSL these days but on 2007 that was my approach - get as far as you can with the DVWP then tweak the template from there.  In regards to the step by step - I'm not aware of any.  I would take the similar approach above - setup up your lists/data sources in 2010 add your XSLTWebPart and get as far as you can in SPD.  Then open it up and update the XSLT based on what you had in 2007.

Comment: Fair enough. With design view being gone in 2013, is the process there just wing it with code?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  There are XSL/XST tools you cam use to help with templating and formatting. Its been a few years since I've really done anything with those tools but at that time I was using tools from Altova.  They are pretty high end and I'm sure there are some less expensive and easier tools to assist with this.